# Unable to Access camera in IOS mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, webrtc

I Am working on a video calling web app which uses webRTC and we want it to work on mobile devices as well. So far everything works fine on Android but on iphone safari browser user has to allow permission to access camera and  mic everytime. Which wasn't a big issue before it stopped requesting users for permission to access hardware. This issue started happening after we moved to a new domain. it is something like `https://dev.somedomain.ext/dev/`.

It looks like it is because of the new domain but is there a way to fix this problem. Ideally I would like
make iphones allow permission always after they allow for the first time (this is how androids are behaving).

I am using below code to request camera and mic.

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video: true }

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't happening due to domain change as I thaught. `Screenshare` API was getting initialised at same the time when webRTC requests for camera and mic. access and this was blocking the request. I couldn't find any reason why it worked on android/desktop but not on Iphones though!.

I Hope this helps anyone having similar problem.